# Android changing activity issues, crashes on selection

Tags: android

So, what I'm trying to do is have a main menu and then press a button, it loads a list of countries.

now I've seemed to have set it up right, no errors I can see, but the app crashes before I load this activity (the lists) the main menu is fine, and I added another button with a blank activity which loads just fine.

logCat is giving me these errors

```
E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM    
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

and I'm not sure what it's asking for beyond the textView

heres my XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#f897"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="#0f0"/>
```

and my Java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class countries extends AppCompatActivity {

        ListView simpleList;
        String countryList[] = {"India", "China", "Australia", "Portugal", "USA","England", "NewZealand", "Germany", "France","South Africa"};


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_countries);
            simpleList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_countries,  countryList);
            simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }


}
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_countries,  countryList);
```

to:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countryList);
```

your code not work because you use default ArrayAdapter with custom item layout

Comment: where is simple_list_item_1 coming from though?

Comment: `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is default layout of android

Comment: Thank You, that works perfectly, now I need to make it so that when I click on one it opens up a new activity I guess ( So it opens a info. page )

Comment: you need use `listview.OnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 1):

You array adapter expects the layout to be a TextView, but it look like R.layout.activity_countries is an activity layout?

Comment: ah ok, so what do I need to change?

Comment: new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_countries,  countryList); that line needs to be something like described here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: hmm, so I'd need to have my array in another xml file?

Comment: Your array can be in the java file, but the array you are using is expecting the layout to just be a textview. So you will need to use something like android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 as the layout or use a different type of adapter. It is common to use recyclerview these days and not listview.

Comment: this is what I'm not understanding though, where is simple_list_item_1 even coming from? I've not declared it anywhere and from that link I don't understand how to.

Comment: It comes with the Android framework and is a default layout included on Android devices that all apps can access.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom adapter and custom view for each listview's row. Check it here: [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)